# What is the weakest condition on the matrices A_k that guarantees v_k->0 => A_kv_k->0 ?

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the weakest condition on the sequence of real matrices A_k that guarantees that whenever a sequence of real vectores v_k converges to zero, the product A_kv_k also converges to zero?

Edit: Boundedness sounds reasonable, but how can one prove that this is the weakest condition? That is, can we prove that if v_k->0 => A_kv_k->0 then the sequence A_k is bounded?

Comment: A simple condition is that the operator norms stay bounded.  But if you want a more coherent answer you should probably specify what you need such a condition for.

Comment: why "too localized" ?

Comment: Since we can't yet make custom reasons for closing, "too localized" is being used as code for "it looks too homework-like to be appropriate for MO." In this case, your question doesn't communicate to the reader that you've put much effort into solving the problem, so it feels like you're asking others to do your work for you, rather than to help you because you've gotten stuck. You can show that boundedness is indeed the weakest condition you could hope for by simply applying the definition of an unbounded operator to construct a counterexample to convergence in the unbounded case.

Answer (score 2):

That they are bounded?

Comment: Absolutely. Why the question mark? This is elementary after all.

Comment: The question mark is due to the triviality of the question. It's a substitute for "like, duh?".

Comment: Ok, but how do you prove that this is the weakest condition?

Comment: It should be easy to show that bounded ==> A_k*v_k --> 0, and if A_k is unbounded then you can probably manufacture a sequence v_k which approaches 0 slowly enough that A_k*v_k does not approach 0.  FOr example in the 1-dimensional case, if A_n = n then you could take v_n = \sqrt{n}.